# Re-Use Sliding Window data for Neural Network for Time Series?

Tags: neural-network, training-data

I've read a few ideas on the correct sample size for Feed Forward Neural networks.  x5, x10, and x30 the # of weights.  This part I'm not overly concerned about, what I am concerned about is can I reuse my training data (randomly).

My data is broken up like so

5 independent vars and 1 dependent var per sample.

I was planning on feeding 6 samples in (6x5 = 30 input neurons), confirm the 7th samples dependent variable (1 output neuron.

I would train on neural network by running say 6 or 7 iterations. before trying to predict the next iteration outside of my training data.

Say I have

each sample = 5 independent variables & 1 dependent variables (6 vars total per sample)

output = just the 1 dependent variable

sample:sample:sample:sample:sample:sample->output(dependent var)

Training sliding window 1:

Set 1: 1:2:3:4:5:6->7

Set 2: 2:3:4:5:6:7->8

Set 3: 3:4:5:6:7:8->9

Set 4: 4:5:6:7:8:9->10

Set 5: 5:6:7:6:9:10->11

Set 6: 6:7:8:9:10:11->12

Non training test:
7:8:9:10:11:12 -> 13

Training Sliding Window 2:

Set 1: 2:3:4:5:6:7->8

Set 2: 3:4:5:6:7:8->9

...

Set 6: 7:8:9:10:11:12->13

Non Training test: 8:9:10:11:12:13->14

I figured I would randomly run through my set's per training iteration say 30 times the number of my weights.  I believe in my network I have about 6 hidden neurons (i.e. sqrt(inputs*outputs)).  So 36 + 6 + 1 + 2 bias = 45 weights.  So 44 x 30 = 1200 runs?

So I would do a randomization of the 6 sets 1200 times per training sliding window.

I figured due to the small # of data, I was going to do simulation runs (i.e. rerun over the same problem with new weights).  So say 1000 times, of which I do 1140 runs over the sliding window using randomization.

I have 113 variables, this results in 101 training "sliding window".

Another question I have is if I'm trying to predict up or down movement (i.e. dependent variable).  Should I match to an actual # or just if I guessed up/down movement correctly?  I'm thinking I should shoot for an actual number, but as part of my analysis do a % check on if this # is guessed correctly as up/down.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small amount of data, and a comparatively large number of training iterations, you run the risk of "overtraining" - creating a function which works very well on your test data but does not generalize.

The best way to avoid this is to acquire more training data!   But if you cannot, then there are two things you can do.  One is to split the training data into test and verification data - using say 85% to train and 15% to verify.  Verification means compute the fitness of the learner on the training set, without adjusting the weights/training.   When the verification data fitness (which you are not training on) stops improving (in general it will be noisy), and your training data fitness continues improving - stop training.  If on the other hand you use a "sliding window", you may not have a good criterion to know when to stop training - the fitness function will bounce around in unpredictable ways (you might slowly make the effect of each training iteration have less effect on the parameters, however, to give you convergence...  maybe not the best approach but some training regimes do this)   The other thing you can do normalize out your node's weights via some metric to ensure some notion of 'smoothness' - if you visualize overfitting for a second you'll find that in the extreme case your fitness function sharply curves around your dataset positives...

As for the latter question - for the training to converge, you fitness function needs to be smooth.  If you were to just use binary all-or-nothing fitness terms, most likely what would happen is that whatever algorithm you are using to train (backprop, BGFS, etc...) would not converge.  In practice, the classification criterion should be an activation that is above  for a positive result, less than or equal to  for a negative result, and varies smoothly in your weight/parameter space.  You can think of 0 as "I am certain that the answer is up" and 1 as "I am certain that the answer is down", and thus realize a fitness function that has a higher "cost" for incorrect guesses that were more certain...   There are subtleties possible in how the function is shaped (for example you might have different ideas about how acceptable a false negative and false positive are) - and you may also introduce regions of "uncertain" where the result is closer to "zero weight" - but it should certainly be continuous/smooth.

Comment: I could make more "sets", but it would be a shame to have to do more than 10 sets per "training window".  I have say 113 months I wish to predict the next month's price.  With multiple regression I was able to do it with 6 months to predict the 7th.  I figured I could do it with ann's and that there would be enough variation in data between 6 sets per "training window"... I would love to use RPROP but I'm having issues implementing it.  Then maybe I could do bath training on 2 random sets within each "training window"

Comment: the generalization is not a big deal.  The net is only for a specific problem domain.  In my case, only for the next set of data.  The net will not be carried forward or used for any new data other than this "7th" set for each "sliding window".  I want it generalized for this purpose.  I achieved something similar in Multiple Regression analysis on small "sliding windows" of 6 months each predicting the 7th month.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-use sliding window's.

It basically the same concept as **bootstrapping** (your training set); which in itself reduces training time, but don't know if it's really helpful in making the net more adaptive to anything other than the training data.

Below is an example of a sliding window in pictorial format (using spreadsheet magic)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5AyC.png

https://github.com/thistleknot/FredAPI/blob/05f74faf85d15f6898aa05b9b08d5363fe27c473/FredAPI/Program.cs
Line 294 shows how the code is ran using randomization, it resets the randomization at position 353 so the rest flows as normal.

I was also able to use a 1 (up) or 0 (down) as my target values and the network did converge.